# LabView Xml flatterned TimeStamp to C# DateTime

Tags: c#, labview

we have a LabView application which generates a XML file containing TimeStamp. 
LabView has [Flatten To XML Function](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/glang/flatten_to_xml/)

XML will look like this

```
<Timestamp>
    <Name>Time Stamp Control</Name>
    <Cluster>
        <Name/>
        <NumElts>4</NumElts>
        <I32>
            <Name/>
            <Val>0</Val>
        </I32>
        <I32>
            <Name/>
            <Val>-309993472</Val>
        </I32>
        <I32>
            <Name/>
            <Val>-679771851</Val>
        </I32>
        <I32>
            <Name/>
            <Val>0</Val>
        </I32>
    </Cluster>
</Timestamp>
```

I have a C# services which reads all these XMLs and process for a dashboard website. I need help in interpreting these `<val>`s and generating C# DateTime

Date Time: **7/23/2018 8:57:25.927 AM**

Some discussion related to this topic is [here](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/XML-Timestamp-Interpretation/td-p/445511)

Comment: Which part of the explanation on the page you linked to are you having trouble with?

Comment: @nekomatic understanding the 4 elements of TimeStamp so that I can generate C# DateTime out of those numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [documentation](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/7900/en/):

> The LabVIEW timestamp is a 128-bit data type that represents absolute time.

Those 128 bits include two 64 bit integers:

> (i64) seconds since the epoch 01/01/1904 00:00:00.00 UTC (using the Gregorian calendar and ignoring leap seconds)

and

> (u64) positive fractions of a second

The flattened XML representation splits each of these to two 32 bit signed integers, hence the four values.
In your example the values are (going from the bottom to the top - mind this "swaping of order"):

```
0             : High 32 bits of the whole seconds part
-679771851    : Low 32 bits of the whole seconds part

-309993472    : High 32 bits of the fraction of a second part
0             : Low 32 bits of the fraction of a second part
```

The 'fraction of second part' is a fraction - it would be equal to 1sec if it was equal the max value of a 64bit number. So obviously you need to divide it by that value (max of 64 bits).

So after combining the parts you can just take the resulting 'seconds part', add it to the 'fraction of second part' and you have number of seconds since 01/01/1904 00:00:00.00 UTC.

The following labview code demonstrates the described reconstruction.
[Flattened Time Stamp reconstruction example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9zeT.png)

Comment: So how do I add these 4 numbers to make it 3615195445?